# cannot push work on git "failed to push some refs"

Tags: git

I have been trying to push my work on github but I get this error :

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\wiki\wiki> git push origin --all
To https://github.com/me50/xxx.git
 ! [rejected]        web50/projects/2020/x/wiki -> web50/projects/2020/x/wiki (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me50/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You should do a git pull because there are new commits on the origin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try `git pull` and then try to push.

If above doesn't work then try this,

`git push --force-with-lease origin` (This will overwrite your remote changes by your local branch.)

The error caused because your origin branch is ahead of your local branch.

Comment: Thanks this actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `git pull` before to merge the changes from the origin remote with your local changes.

Comment: yes  thanks, I did, then I had to ` git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories ` because The error is resolved by toggling the allow-unrelated-histories switch.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ git pull --rebase origin master
$ git push -u origin master
```

Ref: https://www.programmersought.com/article/22301895864/